# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '____'

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

I've been messing around with this code for some hours, and it still give me errors. I want to do an 'automark' for tests, where you introduce the good answers and the bad ones, and it calculates the final mark.

**Code:**

```
class puntuacion:
    def __init__(self, aciertos, errores):
        self.aciertos = int(input("Introduce el numero de aciertos"))
        if self.aciertos > 40:
            print("Numero maximo de aciertos: 40")
            exit()
        self.errores = int(input("Introduce el numero de errores: "))

    def calculo(self):
        totalac = self.aciertos * 0.25
        print(totalac)
        while self.errores > 3:
            totalerr += -0.25
            self.errores - 3
        print'Nota final: ', totalac-totalerr
calculo({})
```

**Error:**

> ```
>   C:\Users\Admin>python C:\Users\Admin\Documents\python\test2.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\python\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
>     class puntuacion:
>   File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\python\test2.py", line 17, in puntuacion
>     calculo({})
>   File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\python\test2.py", line 10, in calculo
>     totalac = self.aciertos * 0.25
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'aciertos'
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call an instance method directly: you have to instantiate the class first:

```
p = puntuacion(something, something_else)
p.calculo()
```

The `calculo()` method does not take any arguments: the first argument, `self`is implicit, and corresponds to the class instance. You don't pass it.

---

You should also remove the `input()` functions from your `__init__`; you're already passing `aciertos` and `errores` as arguments, and generally you don't want to do "complicated" stuff (like user interaction) in the initialization of a class:

```
...
def __init__(self, aciertos, errores):
    self.aciertos = aciertos
    self.errores = errores
...
```

and then:

```
aciertos = int(input("Introduce el numero de aciertos"))
if aciertos > 40:
    sys.exit("Numero maximo de aciertos: 40")
errores = int(input("Introduce el numero de errores: "))

p = puntuacion(aciertos, errores)
p.calculo()
```